# Cakephp send data to model function

Tags: php, cakephp

I have the following function in my `Website model`

```
    public function update_website_status($id = null,$status ){
        $this->saveField('is_approved',$status,array('website_id' => $id));
}
```

Now if i wish to call this function from a `controller` how would i set the `$id` and the `$status`?

I know this is rather basic but i simply couldn't find an example in the Cake Cookbook (Documentation).

Also is the way i am "searching" aka. making sure its the right `website`_id the correct way of doing it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

just try like this

```
$this->Website->update_website_status($id, $status);
```

in your `WebsitesController`

if you want to call this function other than from websites controller just load the website model before calling the function, i.e.

```
$this->loadModel('Website');
$this->Website->update_website_status($id, $status);
```

Comment: thanks will this work for other controllers aswell if i have used the $uses = array('Website'); ?

Comment: @Marc yes you can also use `$uses` option as well

Answer (score 1):

If you have the website ID already in your controller, then you could just update the site directly, like this:

```
public function controller_action() {
    $this->Website->id = $id; // $id has been set somewhere
    $this->Website->saveField('is_approved', $status); // $status has bee set somewhere too
}
```

If you wanted a method in your model so you could call it in multiple controllers, then make sure you load the model:

```
<?php
class FooController extends AppController {

    public $uses = array('Website');
}
```

And then create your model method as you have

```
<?php
class Website extends AppModel {

    public function updateWebsiteStatus($id, $approved) {
        $this->id = $id;
        $this->saveField('is_approved', $approved);
    }
}
```

And call it in your controller methods:

```
public function controllerAction() {
    $this->Website->updateWebsiteStatus($id, $approved);
}
```